# Do I need a doctor's note for bringing medication on an airplane?

Tags: japan, paperwork, health

I am flying Croatia–Japan and I was curious how to go about bringing medication on board. I'm taking my prescription allergy medicine, which is basically just bilastine tablets and fluticasone furoate nose spray. They're in the original packaging.

Do I need a doctor's note? Do I carry it in my carry-on baggage or somewhere else?

Comment: Is this a direct flight or do you have to transit somewhere along the way? Rules vary among countries as to what medications are permitted (eg. some countries in the middle east are notoriously strict about such things.)

Comment: No you don't, AFAIK, so long as it's in the packaging with your name then it isn't an issue in most countries, lest they check because they might not care. However, this doesn't apply to controlled substances like Vicodin or Ritalin where you definitely on't want to be caught by customs officers without a written note for those.

Comment: Although a prescription medicine is exempt from the limit, it will be convenient if your nasal spray is below 3.5 oz (300 ml).

Comment: A doctor's note is needed at the security check if you need to bring something that normally would not be allowed through, like liquids in amounts that exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the website of three various countries and the warnings about bringing prescription medication into Japan: [UK](http://www.japanspecialist.co.uk/travel-tips/taking-medication-into-japan/), [US](https://jp.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/doctors/importing-medication/), and [Australia](http://www.au.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_medicine_en.html). They all essentially say that Japan has a strict drug policy. Up to a 1 month supply is allowed for acceptable drugs, while others (even over the counter medications) are strictly prohibited. I would recommend contacting the Japanese embassy in Croatia or that serves Croatia to confirm.

Comment: "would recommend contacting the Japanese embassy in Croatia or that serves Croatia to confirm." - why can't we do it for OP? I'm sure there's a list of prohibited drugs somewhere.